# Object pointer in .msg file

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I am currently implementing a scheduler for which I need more information on each frame than the message and its standard headers carry. I created an Object containing all the information and now I want to add a pointer to a .msg file pointing to the informatino object. The .msg File is used to tag the information to the frame later on.

For this I have created a new message file.

```
cplusplus{{
#include "inet/common/TagBase_m.h"
#include <cstdint>
}}

class noncobject inet::TagBase;

namespace nesting;

class FilterTag extends inet::TagBase
{
    intptr_t streamFilterID; 
    simtime_t etT; 
    simtime_t startTime; 
    simtime_t endTime;  
}
```

Unfortunately INET v4.1.2 does not allow adding pointers out of the box. That is why I tried to cas my pointer and add an `intptr_t` by including `<cstdint>` instead. However, when doing so I am confronted with this error:

> Error: unknown type 'intptr_t' for field 'streamFilterID' in
> 'FilterTag'

It seems like my import doesn't work as I thought. How would I manage to make my .msg file recognize the `intptr_t` ? Ss there a better way to get done what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line into your message definition:

```
class noncobject intptr_t;
```

It tells the message compiler that `intptr_t` is an external type.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation of this ? I didn't find it online yet.

Comment: Here you are: [Simulation Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:msg-defs:announcing-types).